# How to handle handler again enter into same activity?

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, handler, countdowntimer

I created one handler for calling AsyncTask in background when I start the application its working fine when I re-enter into the application it will call two times in for first one and present one, how can I handle that

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        checkandsave();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 300000); //execute in every 60000 ms = 1 minute
```

Comment: cancel old before starting new

Comment: how can i know its in running and how can i stop it

Comment: store your `TimerTask` in a field, and cancel it before you create new one. Or cancel it when exiting app